# Taking Input from the User

Tags: java, io

What is the difference between taking input from `Scanner` and `BufferedReader` ?

Here is a `BufferedReader` example...

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter characters, 'q' to quit.");

// read characters
do {
    c = (char) br.read();
    System.out.println(c);
} while(c != 'q');
```

And here is a `Scanner` example...

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
char mrArray = new char[10];
// read characters
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    String temp = myScanner.next();
    myArray[i] = temp.charAt(0);
}
```

Is there any difference between the two cases? Are any of these classes likely to be changed in the future? Should I use `BufferedStream` in preference to `Scanner`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A BufferedReader is a simple class meant to efficiently read from
>   the underling stream. Generally, each read request made of a Reader
>   like a FileReader causes a corresponding read request to be made to
>   underlying stream. Each invocation of read() or readLine() could cause
>   bytes to be read from the file, converted into characters, and then
>   returned, which can be very inefficient. Efficiency is improved
>   appreciably if a Reader is warped in a BufferedReader.
>   BufferedReader is synchronized, so read operations on a BufferedReader
>   can safely be done from multiple threads.
>
> A scanner on the other hand has a lot more cheese built into it; it
>   can do all that a BufferedReader can do and at the same level of
>   efficiency as well. However, in addition a Scanner can parse the
>   underlying stream for primitive types and strings using regular
>   expressions. It can also tokenize the underlying stream with the
>   delimiter of your choice. It can also do forward scanning of the
>   underlying stream disregarding the delimiter!   A scanner however is
>   not thread safe, it has to be externally synchronized.

Source : [Scanner vs buffer reader](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Java-1046/2009/2/Difference-Scanner-Method-Buffered.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Scanner is used for parsing tokens from the contents of the stream while BufferedReader just reads the stream and does not do any special parsing.

In fact you can pass a BufferedReader to a scanner as the source of characters to parse and BufferedReader is synchronized and Scanner is not, so its up to you to decide.

*EDIT* System.in is a stream.

Answer (score 2):

The main practical difference was simply that [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) wasn't introduced until 1.5, and thus before that you had no choice but to to wrap `System.in` round various readers and then parse the output yourself to retrieve what you wanted.

Scanner manages a lot of this now for you, so unless you have a compelling reason to use BufferedReader and parse / process things entirely by yourself, I'd generally default to using Scanner - if nothing else because it makes the code clearer.